# Mesh loaded with Assimp displaying partial amount of vertices?

Tags: c++, directx, game-development, directx-11, assimp

I was writing a mesh loader for a DirectX 11 project using C++, and I decided to use assimp because of the experience I gained with the API while learning OpenGL. The loader has no issues dealing with smaller meshes, but when the amount of vertices a certain threshold,  [it completely breaks, displaying only a few vertices (it doesn't show the star on the Cerberus model and its even worse on higher detail meshes).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYEFT.jpg) as opposed to the [original mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucCX1.png).

At first I tried:

```cpp
struct Vertex
{
    struct {
        float x, y, z;
    } position;
    struct {
        float x, y, z;
    } normal;
    struct
    {
        float u, v;
    } TexCoord;
    Vertex(float px, float py, float pz, float nx, float ny, float nz, float u, float v)
        : position{ px, py, pz },normal{nx, ny, nz}, TexCoord{u, v}
    {
    }
    Vertex(){}
};
class Mesh {
    public:
        Mesh(){}
        int Create(const char* filepath);
        inline VertexBuffer* GetVertexBuffer() { return &m_VertexBuffer; }
        inline IndexBuffer* GetIndexBuffer() { return &m_IndexBuffer; }
        inline void DestroyMesh() { m_VertexBuffer.ShutDown(); m_IndexBuffer.ShutDown(); };
    private:
        static BufferLayout layout[];
        std::vector<Vertex> m_vertices;
        std::vector<unsigned int> m_indices;
        VertexBuffer m_VertexBuffer;
        IndexBuffer m_IndexBuffer;
    };
}
int Mesh::Create(const char* filepath)
{
    Assimp::Importer imp;
    const aiScene* pScene = imp.ReadFile(filepath, aiProcess_Triangulate |aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices);
        
    const aiMesh* pmesh = pScene->mMeshes[0];
    m_vertices.reserve(pmeshes->mNumVertices);
    m_indices.reserve(pmeshes->mNumFaces * 3);  
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < pmeshes->mNumVertices; j++)
    {
        m_vertices.push_back(Vertex(
            pmeshes->mVertices[j].x, pmeshes->mVertices[j].y, pmeshes->mVertices[j].z,
            pmeshes->mNormals[j].x, pmeshes->mNormals[j].y, pmeshes->mNormals[j].z,
            pmeshes->mTextureCoords[0][j].x, pmeshes->mTextureCoords[0][j].y
            ));
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pmeshes->mNumFaces; i++)
    {
        const auto& face = pmeshes->mFaces[i];
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < face.mNumIndices; j++)
            m_indices.push_back(face.mIndices[j]);
    }
    m_VertexBuffer.Create(m_vertices.data(), sizeof(Vertex) * pmeshes->mNumVertices, sizeof(Vertex));
    m_IndexBuffer.Create(m_indices.data(), sizeof(unsigned int) * pmeshes->mNumFaces * 3, sizeof(unsigned int));
    imp.FreeScene();
    return 0;
}
```

The Vertex and Index Buffer Creation methods were:

```cpp
void VertexBuffer::Create(const void* vertices, unsigned int size, unsigned int stride)
{
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd = {};
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    bd.MiscFlags = 0;
    bd.ByteWidth = size;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA sd = {};
    sd.pSysMem = vertices;
    RendererBase::Getd3dDevice()->CreateBuffer(&bd, &sd, &pVertexBuffer);
}
IndexBuffer::Create(const void* indices, unsigned int size, unsigned int stride)
{
        count = size/stride;
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd = {};
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    bd.MiscFlags = 0;
    bd.ByteWidth = size;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA sd = {};
    sd.pSysMem = indices;
    RendererBase::Getd3dDevice()->CreateBuffer(&bd, &sd, &pIndexBuffer);
}
```

I also tried loading all models in the file and creating separate mesh objects for each, then drawing each one, but I still got the same results. any help will be very much appreciated. If there is any more information or code snippets needed, I'm always happy to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the issue, it was in my index buffer class

```cpp
class IndexBuffer
{
public:
    IndexBuffer();
    void ShutDown();
    void Bind();
    void UnBind();
    static IndexBuffer* Create(const void* indices, unsigned int size, unsigned int stride);
    void Create(const void* indices, unsigned int size, unsigned int stride);
    inline unsigned int GetCount() { return count; }
private:
    unsigned short count;
    ID3D11Buffer* pIndexBuffer = NULL;
};
```

The count variable was an unsigned short, so the amount of indices drawn was limited to 65535 (the so-called "clipping threshold"). Changing this to an unsigned int solved the problem.